# How to loop through an array of checkbox

Tags: c#

I am working on an windows application and I am wondering what is the way to loop through an array of `checkBox` to see if they are checked or not and have a message box to show what is checked.

Here is the code i am using.

```
CheckBox[] myCheckBoxArray = new CheckBox[6];    
myCheckBoxArray[0] = checkBoxALL;
myCheckBoxArray[1] = checkBoxA;
myCheckBoxArray[2] = checkBoxB;
myCheckBoxArray[3] = checkBoxC;
myCheckBoxArray[4] = checkBoxD;
myCheckBoxArray[5] = checkBoxE;
foreach(var items in myCheckBoxArray)
{
    if(myCheckBoxArray.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code provided should fail to compile with an error message (somehow it is missing from the post). It may be good idea to read about [Using foreach with Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288254%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN...

Comment: thanks, I will look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
foreach(var checkedItem in myCheckBoxArray.Where(item => item.Checked))
{
    MessageBox.Show(checkedItem);
}
```

Comment: var checkedItems = myCheckBoxArray.Where(item => item.Checked), caching list items will be more optimized

Comment: @A.T. That most definitely does not "cache" the result. If you iterate `checkedItems` twice, every checkbox will be checked twice, too.

Comment: yea forgot to add ToList() extension

Comment: the `checkeditem` somehow show cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`. to 'string' :/ should it be checkedItem.ToString() ?

Comment: actually it should be checkedItem.Checked, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sorry for unclear question. I mean when I do something like  `MessageBox.Show(checkedItems)`;, It shows that error

Answer (score 2):

You are looping through `myCheckBoxArray`, where `items` represent each item in the array, so you have to `check whether the item is checked or not` not the myCheckBoxArray.Checked. so your code will be like the following:

```
 foreach(var items in myCheckBoxArray)
  {
        if(items.Checked)
        {
           //Do your stuff here
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont loop not checked items .

```
var checkeeditems=myCheckBoxArray.where(p=>p.Cheked).toList();

foreach(var Name  in checkeeditems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Name  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example code, you are looping through mycheckboxarray, but you are checking Checked property of myCheckBoxArray rather than item. You can alter the code as below and it will give you desired results.

```
foreach (var checkbox in myCheckBoxArray)
        {
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("this one is checked");
            }
        }
```